# upload image to skin path from admin system config

Tags: configuration, magento-1.9, system.xml, upload

In system.xml file you can upload images to /media/... by using:

```
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">modulename/folder</upload_dir>
<base_url type="media" scope_info="1">modulename/folder</base_url>
```

However i need to upload the image in skin/frontend/modulename/themename/css/images directory. I've tried with config="system/filesystem/skin" and type="skin" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Before I explain how you can achieve this I want to say that I don't approve of the upload of resources in folders other than `media`. Your Magento instance should only write files to `media` and `var`.

But if you insist.....

You can't do much only my changing the `upload_dir` and `base_url` tags.
The config input has the `<backend_model>` a class that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_File`.
And in that class there is this method that determines the base folder where the file will be uploaded.

```
protected function _getUploadRoot($token)
{
    return Mage::getBaseDir('media');
}
```

This means that everything is uploaded somewhere inside the `media` folder.
So you need to create a backend model that extends the original one and change the method I mentioned above